# Ruby on Rail: Add Polymorphic address to Devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, polymorphic-associations

ROR newbie here. :-)

### I am using Devise for authentication and have added first_name and last_name to the User model created by devise. I have also created Address model:

create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.string :line1
      t.string :line2
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.integer :addressable_id
      t.string :addressable_type

```
  t.timestamps
end

add_index :addresses, [:addressable_type, :addressable_id], :unique => true
```

end

---

### a partial at views/shared/_address.html.erb

---

### user.rb

has_one :address,   :as => :addressable

# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :firstname, :lastname
  attr_accessible :address_attributes

### accepts_nested_attributes_for  :address, :update_only => true

added the following lines at views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb and edit.html.erb

---

<% f.fields_for :address do |address|%>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/address', :locals => {:f => address}%>

<% end %>

<% end %>

---

<% f.fields_for :address do |address|%>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/address', :locals => {:f => address}%>

<% end %>

<% end %>

---

Now I want to have Devise create an Address when a new user sign up. And the user could fill in the address after sign in. Apparently something is missing or I am doing it wrong. The address fields are not showing at sign_up nor edit.

Please share your wisdom. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The general behavior of fields_for is that the associated object will not show in the form unless it already exists.  E.g. if we were speaking outside the context of Devise, then to get the address to show up on the new user form you would have something like:

```
# users_controller.rb
def new
   @user = User.new
   @user.address = Address.new
end
```

and then the address would display on the form.

Given that this is a Devise-managed form and you do not have direct access to the necessary controller, I'm guessing the best thing to do is to use an ActiveRecord callback to instantiate an address if it doesn't exist already.  E.g. something like

```
# user.rb
after_initialize :create_address

def create_address
    self.address = Address.new if self.address.nil?
end
```

Comment: Thank you @madomausu, 
I have added the callback to the user.rb. It creates a new address when a new user signs up. (id, created, empty fields are nil, and addressable => user) The address partial still doesn't render at the edit registration page, although the server shows it loads Address and rendered shared/_address.html.erb. I will dig around the devise/registrations and see if something I have done around

Comment: @DiZee Were you successful in creating this?